# Why the number of comment in Facebook plugin is different from number of comment in Facebook API?

Tags: facebook

The question is as what the title stated. For example:

- [Social Plugin](http://www.khmerload.com/news/21857)

There are only 2 comments in the Facebook plugin for that link.

- [Facebook API](http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20total_count,like_count,comment_count,share_count,click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://www.khmerload.com/news/21857%27&format=json)

The Facebook API says that there are 47 comments. What is the cause of the different? My thought is that the social plugin only counts the number of comment via the plugin, while the Facebook API one counts all the comments including the social plugin and any comment on the link in the Facebook. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out data from [`Graph API`](http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.khmerload.com/news/21857).

It returns precise data, comment count for a Url, which is commented by a social plugin.

You, on the other hand, are accessing data from table `link_stat`, which is used for, as per [`offcial documentation`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat)

> An FQL table containing counts that show how users on Facebook are interacting with a given link.

In the end, I agree with you, you get all activity for that link on the whole FB.